# Examples where std::vector::emplace_back is slower than std::vector::push_back?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I am currently reading Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++". In Item 42, he claims that e.g. an `std::vector::emplace_back` is usually, but not always, as fast as or even faster than using `push_back`. He lists three conditions under which it should be at least as fast, but does not provide a counterexample in the case where these conditions are not all satisfied.
Can someone provide me with an example where using `emplace_back` would be expected to result in strictly worse performance than using `push_back`?

Comment: It's not really the same thing, but you can't use `emplace_back` for a braced initializer (e.g., calling a list constructor like `vecOfVecs.emplace_back({1, 2, 3});`), so I guess that would make it not as fast as `push_back`.

Comment: `He lists three conditions` which are?

Comment: It would be a really obscure and odd circumstance if `emplace_back` is actually *slower*. It's normally same or better.

Comment: Scott Meyers refers to this exact question in his keynote talk @ Meeting C++ 2014 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smqT9Io_bKo&t=18m25s). Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this boils down to std implementations. Theoretically, emplace should always be as fast or faster, except the reality is that no standard library implementation takes full advantage of that.

He gave a talk on this exact issue a few years ago: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=3427&v=smqT9Io_bKo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=3427&v=smqT9Io_bKo&feature=youtu.be)

Check out the first 1 hour of the talk for a more detailed explanation. The Q&A at the end of the talk is relevant as well.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "`emplace_back` is slower than `push_back`". Considering class that is expensive to construct and cheap to copy, for example class with copy-on-write behavior, or class representing hash value:

```
class Hash {
    public:
    int value;
    Hash(const char *data) : value(very_expensive_hash_function(data)) {} // expensive
    Hash(const Hash &other) : value(other.value) {} // cheap
};
Hash h(foo);
std::vector<Hash> v;

v.push_back(h);        // 1
v.emplace_back("foo"); // 2
```

Then, (1) will be indeed faster than (2). However, such comparision is not fair. When comparing performance, costs of constructors involved should be factored in.

Answer (score 2):

Silly example:

```
std::vector<always_throws_on_construction> vec;
if(vec.size() == vec.capacity())
{
    vec.push_back(always_throws_on_construction());
}
```

would probably be faster than

```
std::vector<always_throws_on_construction> vec;
if(vec.size() == vec.capacity())
{
    vec.emplace_back();
}
```

Comment: What's the rationale for that guess?

Comment: @black In the push back case, you throw an exception before you run any vector code. In the emplace back case you dynamically expand the vector to be able to handle the new element and then throw. Like I said, its a silly example. [edited to be clear an exception is thrown]

Comment: Oh yeah. For some reason I thought you were saying the opposite, that's why I asked.