# push_back vs emplace_back to a std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

A similar questions exist in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941695/examples-where-stdvectoremplace-back-is-slower-than-stdvectorpush-back) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back) but I think we haven't got a clear answer then I remake the question.

The C++11 standards has two ways to add a new element in the end of vector they are `std::vector::push_back` and `std::vector::emplace_back`.

The difference between them is the `std::vector::emplace_back` construct the object in place and `std::vector::push_back` basically copy the object (or primitive type) or move it to the end of vector.

Then `std::vector::push_back` looks the better option to add primitive types into a `std::vector`. For example:

```
std::vector<int> vVec;
vVec.push_back(10);
int iVar 30;
vVec.push_back(iVar);
```

But it is not so clear to me when we talk about objects. Let's take a vector of std::string for example. If I want to add a literal string I shall use `std::vector::emplace_back` and when I want to copy or move a string object I shall use `std::vector::push_back`?

To make more clear what I'm asking about, let's see a few scenarios:

1st scenario:

```
std::vector<string> vVec;
std::string sTest("1st scenario");
vVec.push_back(sTest);  
vVec.emplace_back(sTest);
```

Push_back make a copy of `sTest` and associate to the new element in the end of `vVec` meanwhile `emplace_back` create the string object in the end of `vVec` and copy the content of `sTest` into it.
Which one is more efficient in this case or doesn't matter?

2nd scenario:

```
std::vector<string> vVec;
std::string sTest1("2st scenario");
std::string sTest2("2st scenario");
vVec.push_back(move(sTest1));   
vVec.emplace_back(move(sTest2));
```

Push_back is ready to move semantic, but what happens with `emplace_back`? Which one is more efficient in this case?

3rd scenario:

```
std::vector<string> vVec;
std::string sTest("3st scenario");
vVec.push_back(sTest.substr(4,4));
vVec.emplace_back(sTest.substr(4,4));
```

Because the std::string::substr returns another std::string we have the same situation as the 2nd scenario?

Conclusion

if `std::vector::emplace_back` is more efficient than `std::vector::push_back` only when literals is involved (in place construction), does it really justifiable to be used? If does, can you give me some examples?

Important to note that `std::vector::emplace_back` was implemented in c++11 not in c++0x then I suppose it has a good reason to exists.

Comment: why would you first construct a string and them move it to `emplace_back`? sorry, but I find your examples confusion rather than clarifying. Afaik `emplace_back` saves you from constructing the instance before pushing it, so your comparisons arent really fair imho

Comment: Emplace_back doesn't save me to construct the instance it does in place, in other words a customized constructor.
In fact, I want to know if emplace_back acts exactly as push_back and it has or hasn't some advantage over push_back.

Comment: _"basically copy the object (or primitive type)"_ Primitive types are objects too. Any type you can store in a std::vector is an object type.

Comment: of course you have to construct an instance at some point, but with `emplace_back` you do not need to construct an instance outside of the container, before you push it. In most of your examples you do create an instance before you insert it into the vector, hence it is pointless imho to compare `push_back` and `emplace_back` for those cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take a while to really understand what the advantage to use std::vector::emplace as aschepler said.

I found out the better scenario to use that is when we have our own class that receive some data when it is construct.

To make more clear, let's suppose we have:

1. A vector of MyObject
2. MyObject needs to receive 3 arguments to be constructed
3. The functions get1stElem(), get2ndElem() and get3rdElem() provide the elements necessary to construct a MyObject instance

Then we can have a line like this:

```
vVec.emplace(get1stElem(), get2ndElem(), get3rdElem());
```

Then the std::vector::emplace will construct MyObject in place more efficiently than std::vector::push_back.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't make much of a difference in your three scenarios, since both functions will call one copy constructor in scenario 1 and one move constructor in scenario 2 or 3.

But what if you want to construct a string of 10 `'x'` characters?  In this case, your choices are

```
vVec.push_back(std::string(10, 'x'));
vVec.emplace_back(10, 'x');
```

In this case, `push_back` involves calling a custom `string` constructor and then a move constructor, but `emplace_back` calls the custom `string` constructor directly, saving the call to the move constructor.

A move constructor for `std::string` may not be a huge deal, but `emplace` functions can save when objects don't have an efficient move constructor, and can be used even if the class type has a deleted move constructor for some reason.  (Okay, `std::vector` won't be happy if you delete the move and copy constructors, but other containers would be okay with it.)

Comment: `vector` is fine  if you delete move and copy constructors, you just won't be able to call `push_back`.

Comment: You could also mention that for types with move-operations that are not marked `nothrow` `push_back` will copy instead of move existing elements into a new buffer if it needs to be resized. So unless one really cares about the strong exception guarantee, `emplace_back` should always be preferred.

Answer (score 13):

First lets clarify:

The `emplace` family accepts ***arguments*** for constructors, not the object itself.

Then it constructs the object *in place* with those arguments, it will never construct a temporary object then copy or move it into the container.

That said, taking an object of the same type as an argument is exactly what copy and move constructing is doing, which is why in your examples, they call the same constructors: they are called with a already constructed `string`.

Where `emplace` and `push` is completely different is where `emplace` is called with constructor arguments that is not the object itself: `emplace` does not need to construct a temporary *then* copy into the container.

```
std::vector<std::string> strvec;
strvec.emplace_back("abc")  //calls string(const char*)

strvec.push_back("abc")          //is equivalent to...
strvec.push_back(string("abc"))  //which calls string(const char*) then string(string&&)
```